# Build System в Sublime. Выполнеиние команд cmd

Tags: cmd, sublime-text

Доброго времени суток.
Использую связку из Саблайм + gcc для работы с С. Для этого был создан саблайм-билд:

```
{ 
"cmd": ["gcc", "*.c", "-o", "build.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "build.exe"], 
"selector": "source.c", 
"working_dir": "${file_path}", 
"shell": true }
```

Все работает, консоль открывает готовый файл, но теперь появилась надобность работы с поддержкой юникод. Если оставить

```
"cmd": ["gcc", "*.c", "-o", "build.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k", "chcp 65001"],
```

то цмд ставит нужную кодировку и в остается в папке с готовым файлом. Никакие операнды и виды записи не помогают/

```
"cmd", "/k", "chcp 65001", "&&", "build.exe"
```

Есть ли возможность запустить так несколько команд?
Спасибо.